# Official power supplies sticking out parts

Tags: power-supply

I have bought a new USB-C power supply for a new RPi and the adapter is significantly smaller than the old micro-USB ones, but to my surprise this new power supply also 'suffers' from the '*oversized plug*' issue, i.e. it has parts sticking out.

The old supplies have changeable plugs and I used to think that this maybe the cause but the new supply is Australia-only.

What is the reason behind adding the sticking out parts on Raspberry Pi power supplies?

[image]

---

*Update*

Other plugs in Australia don't have these "wings".

Comment: Probably because different plugs from around the world have different dimensions - and those sticky outey bits represent the biggest plugs - or they are wings, which make it faster :p

Comment: I forgot to add, even though these don't have changeable plugs, the brick itself would be the same regardless of the added plug - I don't know ... I cut the wings off mine :p

Comment: Do other warts in your country have them? May be for a country specific safety reason.

Comment: I believe it was a legal requirement.

Comment: It's a marketing feature. It's there so that Dremel & Proxon can sell more small grinders in Oz.

Comment: Best ask the electronics experts in your country - I guess that some bureaucrat had a free Friday due to his golf being cancelled and decided out of whimsy to have a 'busy day' creating a law that make zero sense in practise.  Every designer / lawyer / architect should be forced to use their ideas before releasing to the public...